# How do I update to the latest version of SASS?

Tags: ruby, gem

This is really stupid but I've been Googling for an hour now and can't find the answer.

I'm on Ubuntu 10.10, and I'm trying to update to the latest version of SASS so that I can use an `@import` rule inside an `@media` rule.

As suggested here; https://github.com/nex3/sass/issues/64, I tried:

`$ sudo gem install sass --pre`

And that seemed to work fine:

```
Successfully installed sass-3.2.0.alpha.35
1 gem installed
```

But when I try `$ sass -v` I get: `Haml/Sass 3.0.9 (Classy Cassidy)` which is the old version I had before updating.

What am I doing wrong?

```
$ which gem
/usr/bin/gem

$ which sass
/usr/bin/sass
```

Tried the answer:

```
$ sass -v
Haml/Sass 3.0.9 (Classy Cassidy)

$ sudo gem uninstall -Iax sass
Removing sass
Removing sass-convert
Removing scss
Successfully uninstalled sass-3.2.0.alpha.35

$ sass -v
Haml/Sass 3.0.9 (Classy Cassidy) (Was expecting an error here)

$ sudo gem install sass --pre
Successfully installed sass-3.2.0.alpha.35
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for sass-3.2.0.alpha.35...
Installing RDoc documentation for sass-3.2.0.alpha.35...

$ sass -v
Haml/Sass 3.0.9 (Classy Cassidy)
```

So it removes the one I successfully installed and leaves the one that actually gets used when I run the `sass` command. Thougts?

Comment: Can you run `which gem` and then `which sass` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Ok, does that tell you anything? :) I'm no good at this tbh.

Comment: [Can you join me in the chatroom?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) There are some further questions I'd like to ask. :)

Comment: Just using `sudo gem update sass` worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we ended up doing was the following:

First, we installed [rvm](https://rvm.io/) using the rails ready one-liner:

`wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/joshfng/railsready/master/railsready.sh && bash railsready.sh`

Selecting option 2 (RVM) when asked.

Then, we did `source ~/.bashrc`

Then we did a `gem install sass --pre` (no sudo).

Answer (score 3):

Remove it and then reinstall:

```
sudo gem uninstall -Iax sass
sudo gem install sass --pre
```

---

New Edit: I've just seen that you might have been using the `haml-edge` gem (which packs its own copy of `sass`). Nuke that and install sass-proper.

```
sudo gem uninstall -Iax haml-edge
sudo gem install sass --pre
```

Boom.

---

Old **Edit** if you've still got stuff left over it sounds like there's been a manual install, another gem has set something up or you've installed it from a package. I'd be tempted to tell you to nuke it from orbit and fix it later.

Run `nano $(which sass)` and see what you're dealing with. In my gem-installed version I see a header like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'sass' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
```

If you see something similar, that suggests there's something fishy and I vote you just run:

```
sudo rm "$(which sass)" "$(which sass-convert)" "$(which scss)"
```

If there's a different header in there, it might give you a clue where it came from. If it's a package you've installed, remove it. If you can't (eg it's a dependency) you could nuke the file and replace accordingly (knowing that it might break the dependency anyway).

But at the end of the day, it's only a Ruby gem. Killing it isn't going to cancel Christmas.

Comment: This sounded promising, but please check my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this on `Linux Mint 14 (Nadia)`, i.e. `Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal)`.

#### 1. Check your environnement

First check you current version of `sass`

```
sass --version # Sass 3.1.19 (Brainy Betty)
which sass # /usr/bin/sass
```

#### 2. Remove distro packages

remove packages installed with the packages manager (i.e `apt-get` or `apitude`) as they take priority

```
apt-get remove ruby-sass ruby-compass
```

*Note:* this can be skipped if you configure your `$PATH` to target the right binary (see below).

#### 3. Install new version

```
apt-get install ruby-full 
gem install sass 
gem install compass
```

#### 4. Test version

```
sass --version # Sass 3.2.7 (Media Mark)
which sass # /usr/local/bin/sass
```

#### Sources

- [Installing Sass and Compass Ubuntu 12.10](http://ndever.net/articles/linux/installing-sass-and-compass-ubuntu-1210)
- [How to install sass on Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS](http://acervulus.info/2012/how-to-install-sass-on-ubuntu-precise-12-04-lts/)