# Successfully installed SASS, but the terminal insists it isn't

Tags: installation, ruby, gem

I wanted to install sass version 3.2.0 alpha.

I first ran `sudo apt-get install libhaml-ruby1.8`, which is what the console recommended  It successfully installed, but it installed an older version of sass.

Just in case, I tried installing it via rubygems:

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems1.8
sudo gem install sass
```

This just reinstalled sass 3.1.17.  As per the recommendation [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/92471/60584), I tried running the following:

```
sudo gem uninstall -Iax sass
sudo gem install sass --pre
```

This stated that sass 3.2.0 alpha was successfully installed.
However, sass no longer seems to work at all.  Typing

```
sass --watch styles.scss
```

...returns...

```
The program 'sass' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
suto apt-get install libhaml-ruby1.8
```

So now I've gone full circle.  What can I do to get sass working from the console?

Comment: gem and distribution package management are not the same thing.  i already did by civic duty on PPAs today

Comment: @aking1012: Ok, thanks for the hint -- I'll do some more googling.  Could you perhaps link to where you already talked about PPAs?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `/var/lib/gems/1.8/bin/` to your path